# Backbone Relational - Deep nested models/collections

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-relational

Having some fun with Backbone-relational.js v0.10.0

I have a JSON object which contains nested models and collections, to keep this simple I have made the example below. A company can have many employees, employees can have one address and many tasks.

```
{
    name: 'Nicks Company',
    employees: [{
        name: 'Bob',
        address: {
            line1: '1 City Lane',
            city: 'London'
        },
        tasks: [{
            description: 'Make this work'
        }]
    }, {
        name: 'Bill',
        address: {
            line1: '1 The Street',
            city: 'Birmingham'
        },
        tasks: [{
            description: 'Make a cake'
        }, {
            description: 'Fix all the things'
        }]
    }]
}
```

In the below JSFiddle (console) you can see that the address is a plain object, also the commented out code for tasks has been disabled as `tasks` is returned as an array.

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nwa29uLv/2/

Neither the address model or the collection of tasks are created as Backbone instances, is this possible or am I pushing the limits of this plugin?

Comment: This is something that has frustrated me too, in fact it's a problem in core Backbone, as many collection function calls will return an array of models instead of another collection object, which would allow chaining and avoid verbosity. What you are looking for can be achieved with https://github.com/mikeapr4/Backbone.hierarchy or https://github.com/blittle/backbone-nested-models

Comment: @mikeapr4 - it works with the traditional relational backbone, he was missing the reverseRelation which tie the sub-models back to the Model. Check the answer below. There is a working example on the documentation too => http://backbonerelational.org/#examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Here is how I resolved the issue. You were missing the
  `reverseRelation`.
- BTW did you look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39995434/creating-nested-structure-with-backbone-relational)? It has a similar issue.

Follow the [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/randomfifaguy/nwa29uLv/3/)

```js
var Address = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({});

var Task = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({});
var TaskCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Task
});

var Employee = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasOne,
    key: 'address',
    relatedModel: Address,
    reverseRelation: {
      type: Backbone.HasOne,
      key: 'employee'
    }
  }, {
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'tasks',
    collectionType: TaskCollection,
    relatedModel: Task,
    reverseRelation: {
      type: Backbone.HasOne,
      key: 'operatesOn'
    }
  }]
});

var EmployeeCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  model: Employee
});

var Company = Backbone.RelationalModel.extend({
  relations: [{
    type: Backbone.HasMany,
    key: 'employees',
    relatedModel: Employee,
    reverseRelation: {
      key: 'worksFor'
    }
  }]
});

var company = new Company({
  name: 'Nicks Company',
  employees: [{
    name: 'Bob',
    address: {
      line1: '1 City Lane',
      city: 'London'
    },
    tasks: [{
      description: 'Make this work'
    }]
  }, {
    name: 'Bill',
    address: {
      line1: '1 The Street',
      city: 'Birmingham'
    },
    tasks: [{
      description: 'Make a cake'
    }, {
      description: 'Fix all the things'
    }]
  }]
});

console.log('Company:', company.get('name'));
company.get('employees').each(function(employee) {
  console.log('Employee:', employee.get('name'));
  console.log('Employee:', employee.get('name'), 'Address Model:', employee.get('address').get('city'));
  employee.get('tasks').each(function(task) {
    console.log('Employee:', employee.get('name'), 'Task: ', task.get('description'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.3.3/backbone-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone-relational/0.10.0/backbone-relational.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I've made the snippet runnable. Also there is a link to the fiddle

Comment: Great! A link to a fiddle is fine if it can't be in a runnable snippet. But it must be accompanied by at least the relevant code sample. But then, now it is redundant since you made the snippet runnable.

Comment: Thanks so much for this, everything is working perfectly :)